# Post request to SPRING BOOT APPLICATION not working from Jquery(front-end) but works perfectly from POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot

> My front end form, here i take two values as input from the User Router Name and Loopback,

```
     <form id = "form" method="POST" name="myForm"  content = "application/json">
    <input id = "setrname"  placeholder="Router-Name" type="text" required />
    <input id = "setloopback" placeholder="Loop-Back" type="text" minlength="7" maxlength="15" size="15" pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$">
    <input value="Submit" class="formBtn" type="submit"">
    <input class="formBtn" type="reset" />
  </form>
```

> Javascript code

```
    var form = document.getElementById('form')

 form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
     e.preventDefault()
     var rName = document.getElementById('setrname').value
     console.log(rName)
     var loop_back = document.getElementById('setloopback').value
     console.log(loop_back)
    var status1 =0;
    var status2 =0;
    var status3 =0;
    var status4 =0;
    var status5 =0;
    var final_status =0 ;
    var flag =0;
    $.post("http://localhost:8081/ping",{"loop_back":loop_back,"rName":rName,"final_status":final_status,"status1":status1,"status2":status2,"status3":status3,"status4":status4,"status5":status5,"flag":flag},function(data){
    console.log(data)}).done(function(){alert('Request done!');})
        .fail(function() { alert('failed, '); });
 })
```

> Spring Boot Post Method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value="/ping",consumes = "application/json")
    public void addData(@RequestBody PingData data) {
        pingdataservice.save(data);
    }
```

> Even though POST getting request successful from web data is not been updated in my DB

Output of Spring when POST request is sent

[io.javabrains.demo.ping.PingData@6b3fbeba, io.javabrains.demo.ping.PingData@343caa92, io.javabrains.demo.ping.PingData@296453b0, io.javabrains.demo.ping.PingData@48166a94, io.javabrains.demo.ping.PingData@5ecad742, io.javabrains.demo.ping.PingData@ff39e33, io.javabrains.demo.ping.PingData@481a5ae] 2020-06-16 20:57:23.614 DEBUG 6832 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/javascript, */*;q=0.01] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json] 2020-06-16 20:57:23.615 DEBUG 6832 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [[io.javabrains.demo.ping.PingData@6b3fbeba, io.javabrains.demo.ping.PingData@343caa92, io.javabrains (truncated)...] 2020-06-16 20:57:23.732 DEBUG 6832 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK

Answer (score 0):

Send request data inside the JSON.stringify(requestdata). it will work

```
ex: JSON.stringify({"loop_back":loop_back,"rName":rName})
```